# python pandas groupby then count rows satisfying condition

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

i am trying to do a groupby on the `id column` such that i can show the number of rows in col1 that is equal to 1.

df:

```
id col1 col2 col3
a   1     1    1
a   0     1    1
a   1     1    1
b   1     0    1
```

my code:

```
df.groupby(['id'])[col1].count()[1]
```

output i got was 2. It didnt show me the values from other `ids` like b.

i want:

```
id col1
a   2    
b   1
```

if possible can the total rows per id also be displayed as a new column?

example:

```
id col1 total
a   2    3
b   1    1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have only 1 and 0 in col1, you can use `agg`:

```
df.groupby('id', as_index=False)['col1'].agg({'col1': 'sum', 'total': 'count'})

#  id   total   col1
#0  a       3      2
#1  b       1      1
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because your rows which id is 'a' sums to 3. The 2 of them are identical that's why it's been grouped and considered as one then it added the unique row which contains the 0 value on its col 1. You can't group rows with different values on its rows.

Yes you can add it on your output. Just place a method how you counted all rows on your column section of your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generalize the solution to include values in col1 that are not zero you can do the following. This also orders the columns correctly.

```
df.set_index('id')['col1'].eq(1).groupby(level=0).agg([('col1', 'sum'), ('total', 'count')]).reset_index()

  id  col1  total
0  a   2.0      3
1  b   1.0      1
```

Using a tuple in the `agg` method where the first value is the column name and the second the aggregating function is new to me. I was just experimenting and it seemed to work. I don't remember seeing it in the documentation so use with caution.